# Is there a way to generate a name containing salah 22,218 times, out of the 135960 limit mentioned below? Along with making rating rounded to 1 dec

Tags: sql, postgresql

So far, this is my entire code, which is almost done gladly, but I have two main issues. Is there a way to round the random, which is a double precision rounded to one decimal place? For example instead of 2.56, it could be 2.6, while 0 could not be possible as a result?

```
with populate_cup_matches as( 
  insert into cup_matches 
  select generate_series(1,624680,1) as mid,
         ('{final,semi-final,quarter-final,16,32}'::text[])[ceil(random()*5)] as round,
         Extract(YEAR from 'epoch'::date+'1 year'::interval*floor(random()*53)) as year,
         floor(random()*1000000)::int as num_ratings,
         random()*10 as rating
  returning *
)
```

And for this part, I wish to generate names randomly, where as I must insert players with names that contain the word “salah” 22,218 times across the entire 135960 limit mentioned below. However I wish the name to come randomly out of pure luck and not in a uniform manner.

```
insert into public.played_in
select mid,
       case when mid<=22218
          then 'salah'||(gen_random_uuid()::varchar(25))
          else gen_random_uuid()::varchar(30) 
       end as name,
       year,
       random()*11 as position
from populate_cup_matches limit 135960
returning *;
```

Is there a way to solve this? Thank you